# delete case insensitive mysql statement not working in php page

Tags: php, mysql

Im using this code to delete match tweeps in 2 table , now my issue is when i execute php its only delete 1 raw it should delete 5 raw case insensitive ,  i try to excute the same sql statement in PMA and its working fine and delete all matchs raw , any clue why this happened when i execute php page

```
<?php
include "dbconnect.php";
mysql_select_db("sdntweep_tweeps", $con);
mysql_query (" DELETE FROM tweeps WHERE screenname IN (SELECT LOWER (screenname) FROM non_sudanese ");
echo " done"
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in your SQL syntax:

```
mysql_query (" DELETE FROM tweeps WHERE screenname IN (SELECT LOWER (screenname) FROM non_sudanese ");
```

should be

```
mysql_query (" DELETE FROM tweeps WHERE screenname IN (SELECT LOWER (screenname) FROM non_sudanese )");
```

note the extra ).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a close paren in your subquery:

```
mysql_query (" DELETE FROM tweeps WHERE screenname IN ".
     "(SELECT LOWER (screenname) FROM non_sudanese ) "); //<-- at the end, 
      // it wasn't there before
```

You'll find that it'll be easier to debug if you get sane error messages from the driver itself:

```
mysql_query ($yourStatement) or die(mysql_error());
```